# Know where android:onClick came from and retrvieve children data

Tags: android, email

My title may be a bit wrong but I couldn't explain myself better in such short words.

I have `ExpandableListView` which each has two children. They're created in the same activity as i want to do the Intent with data from children. The problem is i don't know how to retrive children data.

This is the method which gives the children the data.

```
private void displayContacts() {
    ArrayList<String> namesmails = getNameEmailDetails();
    ArrayList<String> namesphones = getPeopleWithNumbers();
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<namesmails.size();i = i+2) {
        //namesmails[0] == name && namesmails[1] == phone && namesmails[2] == email
        String name = namesmails.get(i);
        String mail = namesmails.get(i + 1);
        String phone = returnNumber(namesphones,name);
        listDataHeader.add(name);
        List<String> currentName = new ArrayList<String>();
        currentName.add(phone);
        currentName.add(mail);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(counter), currentName);
        counter += 1;
    }
}
```

I'd like to create mail intent, so the `currentName.get(1)` from `listDataChild` is the recipient of the mail (let's say for example: `example@example.org`).

For this I have created a method:

```
public void sendMail() {
    //This function is called out on the list_item click!
    Intent mailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO); // it's not ACTION_SEND
    mailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    mailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:" + HERENEEDSTOBEADDRESS));
    mailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivityForResult(mailIntent,1);
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, mailIntent);

}
```

And gave in `list_item.xml` `onClick` value:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="17dip"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
    android:onClick="sendMail()"/>
```

How could i get the data to `sendMail()`?

A bit additional information. I'm trying to display contacts in the `ExpandedListView` in which the name is a header and e-mail and phone are children of certain element thus each list item is created dynamically according to the size of users contacts size. If e-mail is clicked `list_item.get(1)` then the `sendMail()` is launched and Intent is triggered to send mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="17dip"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
    android:onClick="sendMail"/>
```

and in your java code

```
public void sendMail(View v) {
        //This function is called out on the list_item click!
        String email = ((TextView)v).getText().toString();
        Intent mailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO); // it's not ACTION_SEND
        mailIntent.setType("text/plain");
        mailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:" + email));
        mailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivityForResult(mailIntent,1);
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, mailIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also add `android:tag` on your XML to get where the click came from. Something like:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="17dip"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
    android:onClick="sendMail"
    android:tag="mail@address.com"/> <!-- Attention to this line! -->
```

Then, on your `sendMail()` method, retrieve the tag like:

```
// Don't forget to put the View as a parameter for the onClick to work.
// This function is called out on the list_item click!
public void sendMail(View v) {
    String addr = v.getTag(); // Get the tag.

    Intent mailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO); // it's not ACTION_SEND
    mailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    mailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:" + addr));
    mailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivityForResult(mailIntent,1);
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, mailIntent);
}
```